# MAC OS Perforce delete changelist

Tags: perforce

I have a pending changelist that I want to delete. I use p4v client. I know that on Windows I can right click on it and I have delete option, but on Mac this option is missing. Is there other way to delete it? Thanks!

Edit: I'm interested to delete all files from the changelist also if is possible to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way, assuming you want to revert the files on the changelist also is:

1. right click on changelist, select revert- will get rid of all changes to those files.
2. now you should be able to right click and delete the changelist.

Comment: If you don't wish to revert the files, but just want them in a separate changelist, you can create another changelist and drag the files from this changelist to the other one.